# скрипт который проверяет свойство в css jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Как написать на jquery

Если у элемента в css задано свойство display none то идет следующий скрипт. 
  По сути оно сверяет есть ли у элемента в css display none

Я плохо знаю jquery  но представляю себе как-то так

```
if($('.myBlock') == .css({'display': "none"}){
 следующий скрипт
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Если у элемента в css задано свойство display none то идет следующий скрипт. По сути оно сверяет есть ли у элемента в css display none

Вот так можно проверить:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Если не отображается
  if ($('.myC').css('display') == 'none') {
    console.log('Display: NONE');
  }
});
```

```css
.myC {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myC"></div>
```